wp_insert_term is extremely slow
we are using wp_insert_term to add product categories. The problem is, that this command is extremely slow. Does anybody has had a similar experience and found a solution for this? wp_update_term is much faster.
Thanks for your support in advance.
Best regards,
Holger
The code is pretty simple and straightforward:
        $ret = wp_insert_term( $name, 'product_cat', array(
            'parent' => 0,
            'slug' => $slug
        ) );

if I comment this out, everything is working pretty fast, if I enable this piece of code, the execution of the code becomes terrible slow.

can you include the code? You need a specific question that can be answered with facts, this isn't a discussion group so open ended topics don't work here
